# Any plans to change GP toolbox format (.tbx file) to text-based format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, file-formats

Have you heard if esri has any plans to change GP toolbox format (.tbx file) to text-based format in future?

The issue is that we can't track changes in binary tbx file using source control system. With text based format it would be easy.

Most of our tools are .NET (COM) based. Some used for printing are Python based. Therefore we use a custom toolbox (.tbx), not Python toolbox (.pyt).

Or alternatively (maybe this would be even better approach) esri can provide a tool buildTbx which takes some text-based toolbox descriptor file, finds what tools should be in toolbox, what are inputs and outputs, also other files needed to be included in toolbox (.py files) and  creates that binary tbx file as an output.

Comment: Wouldn't the actual question be _"How to track changes in a binary tbx file with <software|s>?"_

Comment: No, I'm not so optimistic about this general approach :)

Comment: And yet that's your real problem. All version control software should support binary data by now, so it's also your simplest solution.

Comment: @Vince I can store binaries in any VCS. But I want to find out what changes were made between version 1 and version 2.

Comment: Not possible -- It's a binary file.  Enhancement requests belong on ideas.esri.com

Comment: @Vince, Not possible What particularly?

Comment: Did you try casting an IGPToolbox to an IXMLSerialize?  Maybe it implements it, but isn't documented.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall : good idea. Maybe it may work to level 1: you can deserialize and serialize some binary crap. However I don't expect anything useful. I found .tbx is in this ancient format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage

Comment: @Vince They don't let me in to ideas.esri.com . Because I troll too much on them.

Answer (score 4):

For your own tools, you can switch to [Python toolboxes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000022000000). This is the closest match to a text based toolbox as being developed by ArcGIS. However, the documentation about these toolboxes still needs to improve.

> Python toolboxes are geoprocessing toolboxes that are
>   created entirely in Python. A Python toolbox and the tools contained
>   within look, act, and work just like toolboxes and tools created in
>   any other way. A Python toolbox (.pyt) is simply an ASCII-based file
>   that defines a toolbox and one or more tools.

Comment: Most of our tools are .NET (COM) based. Some used for printing are Python based. We use custom toolbox (.tbx). Here is a link that compares both types of toolboxes: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Comparing_custom_and_Python_toolboxes/00150000002r000000/

Comment: Actually, Python toolbox is an invention of a pervert mind. .pyt file is a valid python file however no Python IDE will recognize this fact. Further that led to other perversions. Some guys made a good job adding .pyt syntax highlighting to GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as posted: "No, to my knowledge there are no plans to change the storage format for custom toolboxes away from their binary storage."

Now to also support your needs: I suggest investigating a tool deployment paradigm where your toolboxes are generated (or re-generated) systematically based on revisions to the tool source(s) themselves.

I understand this is a time-consuming (and in my opinion not value-added) approach, but if your objective is to document the differences between time-stamped toolboxes, then the toolbox-builder code plus a configuration XML for each toolbox can be compared to yield a result similar to what you get in "compare sources" in Visual Studio's VSS/TFS source code control solution.

Comment: Quite literal answer; though I don't have an idea what 'a toolbox generator' could be if the format is known to esri only.